How do I set up the ability to edit the product name and its sku from the product grid in the admin panel?
I need to add to the standard product grid in the admin panel the ability to edit the SKU and product name without going to the product editing page. I.e., when clicking on the SKU and product name, the input field should appear and there should be an opportunity to change the value. Is it possible to implement this?

For that you might need to overwrite the admin listing for the products using the theme or an specific module.
See this answer or this answer which have been already responded.
You can also use existing modules to handle this like this or this
If they still do not cover your needs, you can hire a developer to make the adjustments to one module to match your needs (that what we are there for)
